# $H^k(\mathbb{C}P^2 \times \mathbb{C}P^2, \mathcal{O}^*(\mathbb{C}P^2 \times \mathbb{C}P^2))$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology

I'd like to try to compute Cech cohomology groups $H^k(\mathbb{C}P^2 \times \mathbb{C}P^2, \mathcal{O}^*(\mathbb{C}P^2 \times \mathbb{C}P^2))$, but I don't know how can I do it. In my notes the author says that we can use Segre embedding. How can I do this exercize? Thank in advance!